# How does gmail send calendar responses?

Tags: email, calendar

What happens if I click on "accept" in a calendar invitation in gmail?

At work I’m using outlook where you can easily see your responses as emails in the sent folder. There does not seem be be anything equivalent in gmail. How is the response transmitted e.g. to an exchange server?